# How do I allow a storyboard to play before completing Tapped event?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I am building a usercontrol (WinRT 8.1 Universal app) that is essentially a button. You tap the button, it animates, and then the handler executes whatever code the developer wants, such as navigating to another page.

I'm probably doing it wrong, but currently, my usercontrol's Tapped event handler initiates a storyboard animation:

```
 Storyboard f = new Storyboard();
        f = this.Pressed_Anim;        
        f.Begin();
```

And then the control instance's Tapped handler (i.e. on the page's code behind) runs as well.

If the instance's handler navigates to a new page the animation from the control template's code behind is never seen because the page navigation happens before the UI updates. I want the animation to be visible before the navigation, just like a standard button.

Am I going about this the right way?

Note: by control is not inheriting Button, it's made from scratch as a learning exercise.

I doubt the storyboard code will help, but here it is anyway:

```html
 <Storyboard x:Name="Pressed_Anim">
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <x:Int32>1</x:Int32>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <x:Int32>0</x:Int32>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to run your navigation after the Storyboard has completed. just subscribe to the completed event like below

```
Storyboard f = new Storyboard();
f = this.Pressed_Anim;  
f.Completed += (s, args) =>
            {
                //Perform your navigation here
            };
f.Begin();
```

**EDIT** Created a quick example to show creating an event in usercontrol.
MyUserControl.xaml has a button a simple animation that moves a rectangle 100 pixels to the right

```
<UserControl
x:Class="App23.MyUserControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App23"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:2" To="100" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="RunStory" Width="120" Height="35" Content="run" Click="RunStory_Click" />
    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Red" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform/>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

MyUserControl.cs

```
 public sealed partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    //Event
    public event EventHandler AnimationFinished;


    //Invokes event 
    public void OnAnimationFinsihed(EventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = AnimationFinished;
        if (handler != null)
            AnimationFinished(this, e);
    }

    public MyUserControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void RunStory_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard1.Completed += (s, args) =>
            {
                //Animation has completed so lets invoke the event
                OnAnimationFinsihed(new EventArgs());
            };
        Storyboard1.Begin();
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml just has a Grid and MyUserControl

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <local:MyUserControl x:Name="myUserControl" />
</Grid>
```

Finally MainPage.cs where navigation occurs

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        //Subscribes to AnimationFinished event of usercontrol
        myUserControl.AnimationFinished += (s, args) =>
            {
                this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));
            };
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        //unsubscribe from event when navigating away
        myUserControl.AnimationFinished -= (s, args) => { };
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the two events are separate - the usercontrol's own code behind does the animation, but the navigation is triggered by an individual instance of the button (i.e. the code could do anything a developer wants, and I have no control over it executing as soon as the first handler completes). They are two separate events in two separate classes triggered by the same button click.

Comment: think I see what you mean. With a custom control I would raise a custom event after storyboard has completed and subscribe to that event in relevant class then perform navigation. Not sure with usercontrol I will try and have a look

Comment: I'm sure that would work, but it doesn't give me what I need. I need the buttons to behave like normal buttons (i.e. I don't want to have extra special code to make them behave normally). I can get the effect I want by putting a Task.Delay in the button instance's event handler before navigating, but it's ugly, and means I have to treat my button differently to other buttons.

Comment: you will need an event as how would relevant classes know your storyboard has finished. Task.Delay as you say is far worse. I'll post my edit anyway

Comment: The built-in controls (and many 3rd party ones) don't need an event, so there must be a way. Task.Delay is better than an event because as least all it requires is a single line of code, and the actual impact on performance is only a fraction of a second when a button is clicked.

Comment: I cant help any more and don't wish to waste any more time on this. Task.Delay is NOT better than event as it is not supposed to be used in this way. How do you think the Built in controls work? they are basically custom controls invoking events on behaviour (which is what you require here)

Comment: Task.Delay is better than an event in this case because it has no downside (it's not blocking anything), and because I can achieve in 1 line of code what your suggestion needs a lot of unnecessary code. The built-in controls need nothing more than a 'clicked' handler, and since that doesn't seem possible with a user control, having one extra line of code is good enough for now.

Answer (score 0):

The following behaves exactly as I want, but since it uses Task.Delay probably wouldn't scale to other uses (I just want navigation to delay for a fraction of a second so a click animation can be seen, making the button feel tactile).

I add a handler in the user control:

```
  base.Tapped += ButtonTapped;
```

With the following code:

```html
private void ButtonTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {           
            Storyboard sBoard = this.Pressed_Anim;
            sBoard.Begin();   
        }
```

Then in the Tapped handler for the control instance I add a short Task.Delay before navigating:

```html
private async void MyButton_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(AboutPage));     
        }
```

That short delay prevents the navigation from starting at the same time as the storyboard, as the control's own handler and the instance's handler on the page seem to be executed simultaneously.

Unless there is a better way that doesn't require extra code outside of the usercontrol's own class, this is adequate.